# Could Anyone Suggest a Way to Find Words From A string?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP/MYSQL for my major project in college. It is a search engine I made.

My database contain results for this sentence '`who is the first president of america`'.

My question is, when user enter the same query without white space (e.g.: '`whoisthefirstpresidentofamerica`') my search engine fails to retrieve results from the database.

Is there anyway to find words from string which doesn't contain spaces?

Comment: Yes. You can use REPLACE(). If the length of the string before and after varies then there's a candidate answer.

Comment: Friends sorry for bad english if my user input 'whoisthefirstpresidentofamerica' how i will retrieve the data ?

Comment: Short answer - you can't and you shouldn't. If you have people who are so lazy that they can't type in spaces in a sentence, they don't deserve results and you shouldn't cater to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the comparison by removing all spaces from both strings:

```
select *
from t
where replace(t.col, ' ', '') = replace(@Val, ' ', '')
```

However, I suspect that you want to use the full text search capabilities of MySQL.  If you are dealing with sentences, this is by far the better way to go.  You can start learning about them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

EDIT:

If your purpose is to investigate different ranking algorithms, then you need to learn about text search and analysis.  A good place to start is with the MySQL documentation on full text search.  However, it does not let you customize the ranking methods very easily.

In particular, you should be storing your text in a "document-term" format.  That is, have a sentence be split into multiple rows, one for each term in the sentence, along with a word-position column.  This will give you flexibility you need to investigate your own ranking algorithms.

Comment: Friends sorry for bad english if my user input 'whoisthefirstpresidentofamerica' how i will retrieve the data ?

Comment: @RahulR . . . You could put the value into the variable `@Val` and use the above query.  Or just replace `@Val` with the string `'whoisthefirstpresidentofamerica'`.

Comment: My algorithm is - First it split sentence into words then retrieve all records which contain any of the word,then shows most appropriate data using some ranking algorithm.'who is the first president of america' can be asked like this 'president the first who is of america' or any combination but the result will be same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` keyword

```
select * from tablename where fieldname LIKE 'value%';
```

Comment: Friends sorry for bad english if my user input 'whoisthefirstpresidentofamerica' how i will retrieve the data ?

Comment: How is your search working? Are you searching with the user input `starts with` or `contains`.?

Comment: first it split sentence into words then retrieve all records which contain any of the word,then shows most appropriate datas